# How to get (χ2 - df) values (x-axis) from a plot generated by `plot(anova(...))` over an object of class "ols" "rms" "lm"?

Tags: r

I want to extract values of points from a plot generated by `plot()`. In my specific case, I fit a linear model using `rms::ols()` and then call `plot(anova(...))` to get a certain plot. I don't know how to find the data underlying the plot.

### Example

```r
library(rms)
#> Loading required package: Hmisc
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
#> Loading required package: SparseM
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'SparseM'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     backsolve

d <- rms::datadist(mtcars)
options(datadist = "d")

model <- rms::ols(mpg ~ am + wt + disp + hp*drat, data = mtcars )
plot(anova(model))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

**My question:** In the plot above we see that the x axis corresponds to a certain scale of χ2  - df. How can I find the specific x values of the points?

Just to be clear, if we call just `anova(model)`, the resulted table **does not** include the specific metric of χ2  - df as in the plot.

```r
##                 Analysis of Variance          Response: mpg 

##  Factor                                   d.f. Partial SS  MS          F     P     
##  am                                        1     5.0772303   5.0772303  0.80 0.3795
##  wt                                        1    52.3144488  52.3144488  8.25 0.0082
##  disp                                      1     0.2649642   0.2649642  0.04 0.8397
##  hp  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)         2    84.9404887  42.4702444  6.70 0.0047
##   All Interactions                         1    17.1025376  17.1025376  2.70 0.1131
##  drat  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)       2    21.3424778  10.6712389  1.68 0.2063
##   All Interactions                         1    17.1025376  17.1025376  2.70 0.1131
##  hp * drat  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)  1    17.1025376  17.1025376  2.70 0.1131
##  REGRESSION                                6   967.4820636 161.2470106 25.42 <.0001
##  ERROR                                    25   158.5651239   6.3426050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right strategy here is not to try to extract the information from the plot, but to poke around in the *plot method* (`rms:::plot.anova.rms`) to find where the relevant information is stored/how it's extracted:

```r
an <- anova(model)
dof <- an[, "d.f."]
chisq <- an[, "F"] * dof
chisq  - dof
```